# Sum children values at each div parent

Tags: jquery

i have the following problem, i m trying to build a grid system, and at each row i have an 'add module' button. I want when the values of the modules are >75% the button will be disapear. My problem is that the sum variable that i use is the same for every row.

```
     var sum = 0.0;
        $('.row_element').find(function(){
$('.current_size_value').each(function()
{
    sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
});
alert(sum);

});
```

chack my jsfiddle to see how it works : http://jsfiddle.net/panos277/8nDp2/

Comment: Just move the var sum within the find?

Comment: Why are you passing function to the `find` method?

Answer (score 0):

The sum variable is not reset for each row.

```
$('.row_element').each(function() {
    var sum = 0.0;
    var $row = $(this);
    $row.find('.current_size_value').each(function() {
        sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    console.log("row", $row);
    console.log("sum", sum);
});
```

Comment: but this is not reset sum for eash row. I each row must have a sum. But how will i add a sum for each row?